# How do you "Set Transparent Color" in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, transparency, outline

I have a graphic logo which is a series of overlapping shapes, where all are filled white. See below:

[image]

I want to set the white color transparent everywhere it appears in the graphic without revealing what is behind each shape. If I try with the general method of setting transparency to 0%, I see all the outlines behind each shape (which is not what I want). See below:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I have tried Knockout groups but cannot seem to get them to work. I ideally do not want to go and individually group each overlapping shape and apply knockout groups to each as there are so many in this logo. Any idea please?

Comment: why not just paint it the same color as the background?

Comment: Because the graphic is going to be printed on t-shirts. So any background, even if it is the same color as the shirt material, appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Method....

- `Select > Select All`
- `Object > Expand Appearance` (if available)
- `Object > Expand` (just Click OK in the popup)
- `Object > Expand` (if it's still available and not screened back)
- **Pathfinder Panel** (`Window > Pathfinder`) - click the **Merge** button
- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to click (and select) a white shape
- `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke`
- Hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key on the keyboard

This..

- Expands all strokes converting them to filled *shapes*.
- The Pathfinder function removes areas of strokes that are behind fills and not visible due to white objects covering them.
- The delete command removes the white objects.

---

This does make the art more difficult to *edit* further in the future. If you feel you will need live strokes and shapes for further editing, then it's best to **work on a copy** of the artwork until you are familiar with how all this will change construction.

Comment: Perfect that works thanks!